# Issue with the contains method and highlighting elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to highlight an element that contains a string written in a textbox. This is the part of the code that's supposed to do it:

```
$("#rightContainer .magnifier").click(function () {
    var a = $("#searchBox").val();
    if (a != "") {
        var foundin = $('div:contains(a)');
        foundin.addClass("highlighted");    
        alert(a);
    }
})
```

The problem is that the whole page gets highlighted. I'm assuming this happens because I have a main container which has its children containers, so the contains method selects the whole main container. Is this the case or is it because of something else, and does anyone have a better way of doing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector will return any element which contains the text you're searching for, in this case `"a"`. This has nothing to do with the variable named `a`. Perhaps you meant to do something like this:

```
$("#rightContainer .magnifier").click(function () {
    var a = $("#searchBox").val();
    if (a != "")
    {
        var foundin = $("div:contains('" + a + "')");
        foundin.addClass("highlighted");    
        alert(a);
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right, but my problem still persists after fixing that. Everything inside the main container gets highlighted, the text outside of it doesn't.

Comment: @user3078638 It will still highlight any `<div>` which contains the text you searched for. Maybe you need to do something like `$('div.mainContainer div:contains(...)')`? Without seeing the HTML, it's hard to know exactly.

Comment: I think it needs to work from the inside out and not allow it on a parent when a child is highlighted... not sure on the most elegant way to handle that. Maybe wrap the text in a span then find the closest parent `div` from there and highlight that? Not sure...

Comment: @user3078638 You probably also want to clear the `highlighted` class on all divs before you apply it to the ones that contain the search string.

Comment: p.s.w.g.: This doesn't feel right but it works... can You think of a better approach? http://jsbin.com/aRubuqOk/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @BillCriswell It depends on the precise needs. If this the page just contains a bunch of divs in a flat list, e.g. a list of products in a grid, OP may in fact want to highlight the topmost element (under the main container).

Comment: Yeah, good point for sure... `.highlightable:contains(foo)` seems a lot less gross.

Comment: @user3078638 If you mean a better approach to removing the highlight, then just call `$(div.mainContainer div).removeClass('highlighted');` before your if block. This is just to ensure that if you click the button multiple times, the highlight gets removed from the previous matches. If you mean a better approach to than this entire highlighting function, you'd probably be better off walking the DOM.

Comment: Well, the code provided by Bill seems to be doing what I had in mind, so I guess I'll leave it at that. Thank you for the quick responses guys.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you only want the div highlighted which is wrapping that searchbox and not any other div. Use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find that div.

```
$("#rightContainer .magnifier").click(function () {
    var a = $("#searchBox").val();
    if (a != "")
    {
        $("#searchBox").closest('div').addClass('highlighted');
    }
})
```